# Open new window on click in WPF, Ninject and Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, ninject, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to set up a WPF app to call the new window on a menu click with the data provider interface injected into the new viewmodel.

Followed many tutorials and created the Bootstrapper for Caliburn, a service locator and module for ninject. So far the main view doesn't need the IDataProvider but I'd like to open a new window on click event.

The Bootstrapper:

```
public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
    {
        public Bootstrapper()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayRootViewFor<MainScreenViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

The Service Locator and Module:

```
 public class ServiceLocator
    {
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

        public ServiceLocator()
        {
            _kernel = new StandardKernel(new ServiceModule());
        }

        public MainScreenViewModel MainScreenViewModel => _kernel.Get<MainScreenViewModel>();

        public NewLayoutViewModel NewLayoutViewModel => _kernel.Get<NewLayoutViewModel>();
    }

 public class ServiceModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<ISqlite>().To<Sqlite>();
            Bind<IDataProvider>().To<DataProvider>();
        }
    }
```

And this is where I got stuck:

```
    public class MainScreenViewModel : Conductor<object>
    {
        private IWindowManager _windowManager;

        public MainScreenViewModel()
        {
            _windowManager = new WindowManager();
        }

        public void NewLayout()
        {
            _windowManager.ShowWindow(new NewLayoutViewModel());
        }
    }
```

since the NewLayoutViewModel requires the IDataProvider.

Not sure, what am I missing, but in my understanding Ninject should take care of this di for NewLayoutViewModel.

Comment: Have a look at caliburn [documentation](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition) regarding screens and conductors. What error are you getting? Seems like, you'll need to register `IWindowManager` in DI container as well to use it in `MainScreenViewModel`

Comment: It won't compile, the NewLayoutViewModel requires an IDataProvider to instantiate. I'm fairly new to wpf and ninjest, caliburn. In web it is done more simple :)

Comment: Ok after reading the documentation I should use the ActiveItem(new NewLayoutViewModel()); but still need the IDataProvider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a good solution from Tim Corey on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5ciBOoMt8U).

Basically the answer is, if you not insist Ninjet, use Caliburn.Micro's build-in DI solution "SimpleContainer".